# How do I add a compiler in Qt Creator, specifically?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm trying to add a compiler in Qt Creator, and I've read a few different answers and none of them work.

I went to tools > options > build & run > kits, selected the automatically found one with MinGw, clicked on "manage" next to compiler, clicked on the 64-bit MinGw, then clicked "apply" and then "ok," and nothing happened. It still says it needs a compiler.

Comment: Why did you delete your own answer that seemed reasonable? It's fine to answer your own question when you find out the solution yourself and you should even accept so that it's obvious the problem is solved. Or did you just write it too quickly and it didn't actually work?

Comment: I thought it would work, but it didn't. I did find the answer, however, which I'll post.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

It turns out that usually MinGW is 32-bit (I tried a 64-bit, but it didn't work). However, if you chose the 32-bit Qt, it actually comes with MinGW, so you really don't have to do anything at all. It's just the 64-bit version that gets more difficult, as it seems less standardized to me.

Thus, I uninstalled the 64-bit Qt, downloaded the 32-bit Qt, made sure to check MinGW (although I don't think I needed to as I had installed it earlier), and install. After that it should work fine.

There are 64-bit MinGW's, but there are a few of them and I couldn't match any to Qt's system.

Comment: I would note that there is little point in 64-bit Qt on Windows. GUI application rarely have use for more than 3GB of memory and the increased memory consumption of 64-bit code probably negates advantages of the more registers available in x86-64 compared to x86. On Linux you just compile everything 64-bit, but Windows software is still mostly 32 bit except where there was serious need and 32-bit compiler is still the default.